# how to separate the columns in a row using grid ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, grid, row

```
  <div class="row" style=" margin-top:0px;height:100px; ">
    <div class="col col-25" style="background-color:#c8c8c8;text-align:center;padding:0px;">
      <div>
        <img src="img/task.png" style="display:block; margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
        <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px;"><label style="font-size:11px;">My Tasks</label></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-50" style="background-color:#413d3a;text-align:center;padding:0px; ">
      <img src="img/document.png" style="display:block; margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
      <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px;"><label style="font-size:11px; color:#fff;">My Documents</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-25" style="background-color:#c8c8c8;text-align:center;padding:0px; ">
      <img src="img/Newsfeed.png" style="display:block; margin:auto;margin-top:10px;">
      <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px;"><label style="font-size:11px; ">Newsfeed</label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i have a row inside it 3 columns using grid ionic, so i want to separate the first column from the second by 5px and the second from the 3rd 5px without affecting the third because when i put margin-left and right to the second column, the third go to the right 10 px;
i want that because i have another row up of this row and i want them vertically aligned, 5px from the left of the phone

Comment: should i reduce the col-50 to col-40 and try the margin-left and right?

Comment: i reduced the col-50 to col-45 and put to the second column margin-left :5px and margin-right:5px so it worksss